# Use of pyzmq's logging handler in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, zeromq, pyzmq

I want to introduce a `zmq` based logging into a Python program. As I was facing `ZMQError: Address in use` errors I decided to boil it down to a simple proof of concept. I was able to run the boiled down version, but not to receive any log entries. This is the code I used:

**Log Publisher:**

```
import time
import logging
from zmq.log import handlers as zmqHandler


logger = logging.getLogger('myapp')
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
zmqH=zmqHandler.PUBHandler('tcp://127.0.0.1:12344')
logger.addHandler(zmqH)
for i in range(50):
    logger.error('error test...')
    print "Send error #%s" % (str(i))
    time.sleep(1)
```

Result

```
Send error #0
Send error #1
Send error #2
Send error #3
Send error #4
...
```

**Log Subscriber:**

```
import time
import zmq

def sub_client():
    port = "12344"       
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)    
    socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:%s" % port)
    # Generate 30 entries
    for i in range (30):
        print "Listening to publishers..."
        message = socket.recv()
        print "Received error #%s: %s" % (str(i), message)
        time.sleep(1)

sub_client()
```

Result

```
Listening to publishers...
```

So the subscriber is locked at the call of `socket.recv()`. I started publisher and subscriber in different consoles. Both processes appear when I use netstat:

```
C:\>netstat -a -n -o | findstr 12344
  TCP    127.0.0.1:12344        0.0.0.0:0              LISTEN          1336
  TCP    127.0.0.1:12344        127.0.0.1:51937        ESTABLISHED     1336
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51937        127.0.0.1:12344        ESTABLISHED     8624
```

I fail to see my mistake here, any ideas?

In addition to the problem at hand, how do I use this zmq listener in general.
Do I have to create one instance of the `PUBHandler` per process and then add it to all instances of `logger` (`logging.getLogger('myapp')` creates a own logger instance, right?) or do I have to create an own `PUBHandler` for all of the different classes I use? As the `PUBHandler`class has a `createLock()` I assume that it is not thread save...

For completness I want to mention the [doc of the PUBHandler class](http://pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/zmq.log.handlers.html#module-zmq.log.handlers)

I am using a python(x,y) distribution at Win7 with python 2.7.10 and pyzmq 14.7.0-14

[update]
I ruled out the the windows firewall as the source of the missing packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on the subscriber side. Initially a subscriber filters out all messages, until a filter is set. Use `socket.setsockopt(opt, value)` function to archive this.
The `pyZMQ` description is not very clear about the use of this function:

> **getsockopt(opt)**  get default socket options for new sockets created by
>   this Context

But the documentation of the `zmq_setsockopt` function is quite clear ([see here](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-setsockopt)):

> **int zmq_setsockopt (void *socket, int option_name, const void *option_value, size_t option_len)**
>
> ...
>
> **`ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE`**: Establish message filter The `ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE` option shall establish a new message filter on a `ZMQ_SUB` socket.
>   Newly created `ZMQ_SUB` sockets shall filter out all incoming
>   messages, therefore you should call this option to establish an
>   initial message filter.

So the solution is to set a filter with `socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE,filter)`, where filter is the string you want to filter for. Use `filter=''` to show all messages. A filter like `filter='ERROR'` will only display the error messages and suppress all other types like `WARNING`,`INFO` or `DEBUG`.

With this the `sub_client()` function looks like this:

```
import time
import zmq

def sub_client():
    port = "12344"       
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)    
    socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:%s" % port)
    socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE,'')


    # Process 30 updates
    print "Listening to publishers..."
    for i in range (30):       
        print "Listening to publishers..."
        message = socket.recv()
        print "Received error #%s: %s" % (str(i), message)
        time.sleep(1)

sub_client()
```

Comment: I think additionally you want `message = socket.recv_multipart()`. For me the zmq logger is sending the message in 2 parts, with the log level first then the actual message.

Answer (score 2):

I know it is an older post, but if someone lands here this is what the subscriber looks like

```
def sub_client():
    port = "12345"       
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)    
    socket.connect("tcp://localhost:%s" % port)
    socket.subscribe("")
    
    # Process 30 updates
    for i in range (30):
        print("Listening to publishers...")
        message = socket.recv()
        print("Received error #%s: %s",str(i), message)
        time.sleep(1)

    sub_client()
```

And Publisher looks like

```
import zmq
import logging
import time
from zmq.log.handlers import PUBHandler

port = "12345"       
context = zmq.Context()
pub = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
pub.bind("tcp://*:%s" % port)

handler = PUBHandler(pub)
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logger.addHandler(handler)
for i in range(50):
    logger.error('error test...')
    print("publish error",str(i))
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Ok so socket.subscribe("") is the high level call for socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE,""'). Good to know, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you missed to set PUB socket in server.

something like this should do,

```
publisher = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
publisher.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:12344')
zmqh = PUBHandler(publisher)
logger = logging.getLogger('myapp')
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logger.addHandler(zmqh)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: @Akhay according to the doc, `handler = PUBHandler('inproc://loc')` should be equivalent to seperatly creating the socket and bind it to the interface, but I will give it a try

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but this did not change anything. I still receive no logs at the subscriber side.